# UPDATE Table in Stored Procedure With Multiple Joins

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a Stored Procedure that returns desired query results. Works great.

```
USE [Productivity]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProjectsBySite]
(
@idsite int
)
AS  
    SELECT l.FirstName, l.LastName,s.SiteName, p.ProjectName, p.StartDate, 
           p.EndDate, pz.SavingsDate, pz.PlannedSavings,pz.ActualSavings
    FROM ((((pt_Site as s
    inner join pt_ProjectsSites as ps on s.IDSite = ps.Site_id)
    inner join pt_Projects as p on ps.Project_id = p.IDProjects)
    inner join pt_ProjectSavings as pz on p.IDProjects = pz.Project_id)
    inner join pt_Personnel as l on p.Personnel_id = l.IDPersonnel)
    WHERE IDSite = @idsite
RETURN
```

What I would like to do is use this same query to UPDATE the ActualSavings field in the pt_ProjectSavings table.

Here is what I tried but when I execute, the procedure returns nothing. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
USE [Productivity]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSavings]
(
@idsite int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE pz
    SET Project_id = 1  
        FROM ((((pt_Site as s
        inner join pt_ProjectsSites as ps on s.IDSite = ps.Site_id)
        inner join pt_Projects as p on ps.Project_id = p.IDProjects)
        inner join pt_ProjectSavings as pz on p.IDProjects = pz.Project_id)
        inner join pt_Personnel as l on p.Personnel_id = l.IDPersonnel)
        WHERE IDSite = @idsite
END
```

I'm sure it's more than one thing and I know I need to add the SELECT:

```
SELECT l.FirstName, l.LastName,s.SiteName, p.ProjectName, p.StartDate, 
       p.EndDate, pz.SavingsDate, pz.PlannedSavings,pz.ActualSavings
```

I just can't figure get the syntax.

Comment: What are you expecting the procedure to "return"?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're askin here. What do you mean when you say it doesn't "return" anything. Once you run this procedure it will likely only tell you how many rows were changed.

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm hoping the procedure will return the queried data (based on what fields I SELECT) and then I can type into the ActualSavings field and UPDATE back to the table. I'm trying to update data from a query. Maybe I have this all wrong and it's not possible the way I think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding what you mean, and you want to update a table after selecting certain records, and you're using SSMS (which is a lot of assumptions) If that is the case, try this:
Right click on the table and select Edit Top 200 Rows. This will show you the table. Then, at the top left corner click the SQL button that looks like the attached image. That will open a query window that shows the select. If you replace the original select with your select query (not the update, just the select statement), you will then get the results and be able to edit the rows below it. I hope this makes sense. Based on what you're asking, it seems like you want to edit the table itself. If you want a systemic update statement to work, you'd need a file or some other input through a webpage or form to be capturing the value and passing it to SQL to update. That doesn't look like what you're doing here. Do exercise caution, this is a live update to a real table. Any changes you make are permanent.

[image: SQL Button to Edit Table]

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I thought I could create a stored procedure that I can call to a form (C# WPF using EF 6.0). Then place the data in a Datagrid and write back to the SQL table from the Datagrid that is calling the Stored Procedure. Sounds like I can't do this the way I thought I could and I have to pass the value to SQL from my form as you suggested. If I understood your answer correct, I will go ahead and mark as the Answer. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: great! glad to help. There are many ways to approach it, but the best way is what you're doing. One step at a time will give a good understanding. You can create a stored proc with a variable that passes to the table like you have it above but the stored proc where clause would have to isolate the individual line you want to update. Like a spreadsheet cell - you want to isolate that "cell" in the table using the query. The update query you have above will update every record in the Actual Column for that site ID.

Answer (score 0):

**you must select your desired result in the end**
it can not return anything when you update record in query .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSavings]
(
@idsite int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE pz
    SET Project_id = 1  
        FROM ((((pt_Site as s
        inner join pt_ProjectsSites as ps on s.IDSite = ps.Site_id)
        inner join pt_Projects as p on ps.Project_id = p.IDProjects)
        inner join pt_ProjectSavings as pz on p.IDProjects = pz.Project_id)
        inner join pt_Personnel as l on p.Personnel_id = l.IDPersonnel)
        WHERE IDSite = @idsite

--then select your data
 SELECT l.FirstName, l.LastName,s.SiteName, p.ProjectName, p.StartDate, 
       p.EndDate, pz.SavingsDate, pz.PlannedSavings,pz.ActualSavings
FROM ((((pt_Site as s
inner join pt_ProjectsSites as ps on s.IDSite = ps.Site_id)
inner join pt_Projects as p on ps.Project_id = p.IDProjects)
inner join pt_ProjectSavings as pz on p.IDProjects = pz.Project_id)
inner join pt_Personnel as l on p.Personnel_id = l.IDPersonnel)
WHERE IDSite = @idsite
END
```

however if you just want to confirm data has been updated or not **you can use  @@ROWCOUNT**
just use select  **@@ROWCOUNT**  in the end and you will get no of rows affected in database.